# Python MultiThreading For Downloads

Tags: python, file, download, simultaneous

I need to download 2 diffrent files at the time.

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('http://example.com/test1.zip', "C:\Test\test1.zip")
urllib.urlretrieve('http://example.com/test2.zip', "C:\Test\test2.zip")
```

I need to download them at the same time. 
Thank you

Comment: You can try this: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use standard python threading for this.  You will need to create a class that represents a separate thread for each download, then start each thread.

Something like:

```
import urllib
from threading import Thread

class Downloader(Thread):
    def __init__(self, file_url, save_path):
        self.file_url = file_url
        self.save_path = save_path


    def run():
        urllib.urlretrieve(self.file_url, self.file_path)


Downloader('http://example.com/test1.zip', "C:\Test\test1.zip").start()
Downloader('http://example.com/test2.zip', "C:\Test\test2.zip").start()
```

Writing this off the top of my head, so not guaranteed to work.  The key is to subclass the Thread class and override the run() function, then start the thread.

Regarding Dave_750's answer, threading is actually effective in this situation because the download operation is I/O, not interpreting Python code, so the GIL isn't really an issue.  I use threads for sending multiple emails, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Use multiprocessing.pool.  I use it for that purpose a lot and it works perfectly. Threading won't gain you much as the Gil still only allows one to work at a time

Answer (score -1):

```
#import libraries for multithreaded applications
from multiprocessing import Pool

#import libraries for including requests.urlretrieve() function
from urllib import request

#import datetime libraries for date/ time operations
import datetime as dt

#import OS libraries for file and directory operations
import os

#import all functions from grib_downloader.py file - for testing purposes

#function to download a file from FTP link (ftp path) and save it at file_path location.
def download_func(args):
    ftp_path, file_path = args #args is a list with two values which unpacks into the variables ftp_path and file_path respectively
    request.urlretrieve(ftp_path, file_path) #python inbuilt function, part of urllib.requests library. needs an ftp/http url and a path/filename to save the downloaded file

    return ' '.join([ftp_path, ' file saved at location ', file_path])#function returns the url and the location where the file is saved as a string

#defines the main function that implements multitasking routines
def main():
#defines variables that are used for defining the download path for multiple files. in my case, I was downloading a bunch of weather GRIB2 files from an FTP site.

    parameters = ['CB', 'ICE', 'CAT', 'CB_0.25', 'ICE_0.25', 'TURB_0.25'];
    forecast_hour = "1200";
    t_folder = ['T+06', 'T+09', 'T+12', 'T+15', 'T+18', 'T+21', 'T+24', 'T+27', 'T+30', 'T+33', 'T+36'];
    
#create two blank lists to store the urls of the files to be downloaded and the path/filenames where they need to be saved in the computer
    iterable = [] # list to store the urls
    args = [] # list to store the download filenames
    new_iterable = []
#for loop to create a list of urls that comprise all files that need to be downloaded and filenames with which they need to be saved by using the listvariable.append() function
    for param in parameters:
        for folder in t_folder:
            iterable.append('ftp://sa1indsds01:kocac0fo@sadisftp.metoffice.gov.uk/GRIB2/COMPRESSED/EGRR/' + param + '/'
                            + folder + '/' + folder + '_' + forecast_hour)
            args.append('D:\\WINDTEMP\\'+ param + '\\' + folder +'_'+ forecast_hour)
    print (iterable)
    print (args)
#for loop to create a new list which is a 2D array comprising the iterable[] and args[] lists as made above. the range is 66 as there were a total of 66 files that i wanted to download. this can be changed as per ones requirement
    for i in range(0, 66):
        new_iterable.append((iterable[i], args[i]))
    print(new_iterable)# prints to check if the new list is made as required
#multitasking magic happens after this. using the imap_unordered(func_name, iterable_arguments) feature of python multiprocessing library
    n_core = 8
    p = Pool(n_core) #declare object p as instance of class Pool()
    for r in p.imap_unordered(download_func, new_iterable):# do not change this part of the code as it is where the multitasking occurs
        print(f"{r}. download successful")
#call the main() function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have made this code to simultaneously download 66 GRIB2 weather files using the imap_unordered() function. it worked for me as is. one will need to edit the url and filenames as per their computer for the code to work after being copied as is. hope this helps in your implementation. Thanks to all contributors from whom i learn a lot everyday.

Comment: This answer is not actually a response to the question. It is full of unnecessary detail.